# How do I simulate microphone input?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I want to, when in a skype call and gaming, use a soundboard to play sounds that can come in hilariously depending on what is happening. I already have this system in place, but it depends on a property of my old headphones - whatever is played on the headphones is recorded by my microphone.

My old headphones recently broke and my new ones don't have this. This can be for the better, however I want to continue using my soundboard. Right now I am using this command, triggered by pressing a button on my keyboard:

```
paplay file.ogg
```

This obviously causes `file.ogg` to be played to my headphones. The microphone on my older headphones would register this sound, my new ones don't.

So the solution would be to do something like this:

```
paplay --device=/dev/snd/microphone file.ogg
```

I searched half the internet on how to do that, and it turns out that the `--device` parameter doesn't work like that, and that there is no `/dev/` device for my microphone.

What would be the better solution?

Currently I am using ALSA and PulseAudio to handle my sound.